# PowerPivot - How to get the sum of a column based on a distinct key (different column)

Tags: powerpivot

Say I have an Excel table like the following:

```
Person        Category        Rate           Project
A             Developer       1              Project A
A             Developer       1              Project B
A             Developer       1              Project C
B             Tester          0.5            Project A
C             Developer       1              Project A
```

I want to create a pivot table that calculates the sum of the rates per category per distinct person. In other words, Project column will be ignored, and what I want to see is something like:

```
Category              Rate
Developer             2
Tester                0.5
```

Developer is 2 because you have A and C, tester is 0.5 because you only have B with a rate of 0.5. The rate of A is 1, and should be taken distinctly.

Is there a way in PowerPivot that I can aggregate a column based on distinct values on a different column? In this case, the key is the Person column, and I want just a distinct evaluation of the Rate to be visible (not the sum of all rows for person A, which is about as far as I am getting with my experiments). I tried turning the rate calculation into an average - see below

```
=AVERAGEX(VALUES(ResourceTracking[Person]), [Rate])
```

But the resulting table averages it at the Category Level, not the Person Level

```
Category              Rate
Developer             2
   A                  3
   C                  1
Tester                0.5
   B                  0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close - the 'X' functions have a tricky, non intuitive way of working which you should look to become familiar with as they are extremely powerful.

This should do what you are looking for, it basically iterates the average function over the people and then adds the results together.

`=SUMX(VALUES(ResourceTracking[Person]), AVERAGE(ResourceTracking[Rate]))`

You might get weird answers for totals so either turn them off or look into HASONEVALUE().

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't use it off the bat. What I did was to count the number of rows a person appears in and then get the average rate as you did here in a different calculated field. Using that calculated field, I am able to create the breakdown I need